# Can't use jsPDF-AutoTable is not a function since v3.5.13 (jsPDF v2.1.1)

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

When I was using older versions of the libraries, I could create pdf just fine. But since these new versions I can't. Earlier I just downloaded jspdf.min.js file, but now I can see various of versions, like umd, es.. But I don't know, what to use (?), so I downloaded **umd** version.
I don't use angular or node.js, so I can't use `require` or `import` (with import I have an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`) instructions in my javascript code before creating pdf document. So I'm using  `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;` to to use jsPDF class (without it I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined", after line `const doc = new jsPDF();`).
But I want to use the plugin AutoTable also and in official page of the plugin https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable the author uses import or require, for me it doesn't work. When I try

```
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
const doc= new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({
  head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
  body: [
    ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
    ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Spain'],
  ],
})
```

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: pdf.autoTable is not a function`. How could I use the libraries right?
I guess jsPDF works for me with version **umd** and `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;` (I created just a simple document with a string and it worked), but AutoTable doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I successfully tried it for the newer versions of jspdf (version 2.5.1) and autotable (version 3.5.25).

Minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jspdf-autotable demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>save pdf modal will pop up automatically</div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.25/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
      const doc= new jsPDF();
      doc.autoTable({
        head: [['Name', 'Email', 'Country']],
        body: [
          ['David', 'david@example.com', 'Sweden'],
          ['Castille', 'castille@example.com', 'Spain'],
        ],
      })
      doc.save("demo.pdf");
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me after trying 16 other methods since I am not using node

Answer (score 1):

The only solution, that works for me now, is to save the code of jsPDF and AutoTable in the same file. It's not good idea, I know, I would like to have them in separate files, but I haven't founded another way. It anybody could tell a better way to avoid the errors, it would  be great

Answer (score -1):

Export autoTable method, **import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'**

```
function createPdf() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
const head = [['ID', 'Country', 'Index', 'Capital']]
const data = [
[1, 'Finland', 7.632, 'Helsinki'],
[2, 'Norway', 7.594, 'Oslo'],
[3, 'Denmark', 7.555, 'Copenhagen'],
[4, 'Iceland', 7.495, 'Reykjavík'],
[5, 'Switzerland', 7.487, 'Bern'],
[9, 'Sweden', 7.314, 'Stockholm'],
[73, 'Belarus', 5.483, 'Minsk'],
]
autoTable(doc, {
head: head,
body: data,
didDrawCell: (data) => {
console.log(data.column.index)
},
})
doc.save('repro.pdf');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work also. I still have the error Uncaught ```TypeError: pdf.autoTable is not a function```

Comment: You should call only autoTable method, not pdf.autoTable.

Comment: anyway ```Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined```. If I use ```const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;``` before function call I'll get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: autoTable is not defined```

Comment: What about downloading o CDN dist files?

Comment: Also after I've downloaded whole dist files, it didn't help me. As I wrote in the answer to this post, the only solution, that helped me is to save the code of jsPDF and the plugin in the same file. I don't know, why only this way works for me.. But at least something